# What is the necessary version of spark streaming kafka?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am using *`spark-core_2.10-2.0.2`* and *`kafka_2.10-0.10.0.1`*. I want to use *`spark-streaming-kafka`*.

What version of *`spark-streaming-kafka`* should I use?

Answer (score 0):

Your `build.sbt` will contain something like this as you are using kafka 0.10.x:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11" % "2.0.0"
```

Support info for `spark-kafka-connector` are [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/streaming-kafka-integration.html). Integration info is [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html).